# How can I answer several emails at once?

Tags: gmail

Is there a way I can answer to all the selected mails at once?

In this case: I was given the task to review the CVs of some people that want to apply for a job on my company, so I manually selected those mails (they're like 50+) and added them to a label. What I want now is to reply with an acknowledgement mail to let them know their applications aren't unattended. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Google Chrome as a browser, you could try the [**Batch Reply for Gmail**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/batch-reply-for-gmail/jkeciloajjlchlmbjjogifpdkljppbei) Chrome extension.

It is featured in quite a lot of websites, including [on Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5935294/batch-reply-for-gmail-makes-replying-to-similar-emails-simple).

This extension basically adds a "Reply" button after you select a few emails so you can reply to them all at once.

I tried it and it works perfectly fine. What it does is it takes the e-mails of all selected conversations, and open a new window with a "Compose Message" Window and the extension pre-fills email addresses into the "To:" box!

Comment: It sounds interesting, though I was looking for a vanilla Chrome/Google approach it may be the only solution. I'll try it as soon as I get on a computer, thank you.

Comment: Oh, I just checked it, and that article is about 2 years old, I hope it still works!